# sklearn KernelDensity score_samples giving values greater than 0

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, gaussian, kernel-density

I am using `sklearn` `KernelDensity` function to estimate density and then evaluate pdf at some points using `score_samples` function but the values returned by the `score_samples` function are much greater than 0 which shouldn't be the case because as per [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity) it returns `log(density)` *[**Documentation**: The array of log(density) evaluations. These are normalized to be probability densities, so values will be low for high-dimensional data.]*

```py
from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(0, 1, [50, 10]) #50 data points, dimension=10
data_kde = KernelDensity(kernel="gaussian", bandwidth=0.2).fit(data)
output = data_kde.score_samples(data)

#print(output)
output = array([19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645,
       19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645,
       19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645,
       19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645,
       19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645,
       19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645,
       19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645,
       19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645,
       19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645,
       19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645, 19.94484645])
```

Since density lies in [0, 1], `log(density)` should be between `(-Inf, 0]` unlike `19.9448` shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probability densities don't have to be between [0,1]. They are densities and not an exact probability. The Wikipedia page gives a good overview of pdfs.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function